# Strange Build Error .Net Core Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

Installed on my machine is:

- Visual Studio Pro 2015
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
- .NET Core 1.0.1 tools Preview 2

Note: Build error occurs on a Windows 10 machine and a Windows 7 machine, but build does work on another  Windows 7 machine.

So I git clone a .Net Core project from another developer and when I try to build in Visual Studio 2015 I am getting the error

"The system cannot find the file specified in Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets line 262"

Go to line 262 in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets line 262 I see

```
    <Dnx
  RuntimeExe="$(SDKToolingExe)"
  Condition="'$(_DesignTimeHostBuild)' != 'true'"
  ProjectFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
  Arguments="$(_BuildArguments)"
  />
```

If delete this section from Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets the project builds.

I know dnx is the old .Net Core tooling, my guess is something in the project.json for the class library is legacy to the old dnx tooling and the new 1.0.1 Preview 2 .Net Core tooling I have installed is deferring that legacy project.json entry to the old dnx tooling entry in Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets but since I do not have dnx tooling installed, the build fails, of course, this is just a guess.

I have extensively searched online about this issue, I [found an article](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2578) stating to put `"type": "platform"` for `Microsoft.NETCore.App` dependency in the project.json but I am not using that dependency, I tried adding `"type": "platform"` to my `"NETStandard.Library"` dependency but that did not help, here is my project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.1-*",

  "dependencies":
  {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "TSO.ProductItemList.Model": "1.0.2"
  },

  "frameworks":
  {
    "netstandard1.6":
    {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "scripts":
  {
    "postcompile":
    [
      "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %compile:Configuration%",
      "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NuGet\\nuget\" push \"%project:Directory%\\bin\\%compile:Configuration%\\%project:Name%.%project:Version%.nupkg\" -s http://foo/NugetServer/ -apikey testkey"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TSO.ProductItemList.Model, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "C:\projects\tsl\ProductItemList\src\TSO.ProductItemList.Model" --configuration Debug --no-dependencies
1>  Project TSO.ProductItemList.Model (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.
1>  Compiling TSO.ProductItemList.Model for .NETStandard,Version=v1.6
1>  Producing nuget package "TSO.ProductItemList.Model.1.0.2" for TSO.ProductItemList.Model
1>  TSO.ProductItemList.Model -> C:\projects\tsl\ProductItemList\src\TSO.ProductItemList.Model\bin\Debug\TSO.ProductItemList.Model.1.0.2.nupkg
1>  Producing nuget package "TSO.ProductItemList.Model.1.0.2.symbols" for TSO.ProductItemList.Model
1>  TSO.ProductItemList.Model -> C:\projects\tsl\ProductItemList\src\TSO.ProductItemList.Model\bin\Debug\TSO.ProductItemList.Model.1.0.2.symbols.nupkg
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : The system cannot find the file specified
2>------ Build started: Project: TSO.ProductItemList.Client, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "C:\projects\tsl\ProductItemList\src\TSO.ProductItemList.Client" --configuration Debug --no-dependencies
2>  Project TSO.ProductItemList.Client (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.
2>  Compiling TSO.ProductItemList.Client for .NETStandard,Version=v1.6
2>  Producing nuget package "TSO.ProductItemList.Client.1.0.1" for TSO.ProductItemList.Client
2>  TSO.ProductItemList.Client -> C:\projects\tsl\ProductItemList\src\TSO.ProductItemList.Client\bin\Debug\TSO.ProductItemList.Client.1.0.1.nupkg
2>  Producing nuget package "TSO.ProductItemList.Client.1.0.1.symbols" for TSO.ProductItemList.Client
2>  TSO.ProductItemList.Client -> C:\projects\tsl\ProductItemList\src\TSO.ProductItemList.Client\bin\Debug\TSO.ProductItemList.Client.1.0.1.symbols.nupkg
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : The system cannot find the file specified
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Give VS 2017 a try. Old tooling is no longer actively maintained by Microsoft.

Comment: @LexLi VS 2015 is considered old tooling? Why is the first step of Microsoft's installation instructions for .NET Core: "Download Visual Studio 2015"? https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015

Comment: simply because it is not yet March 7. They probably do not want to update the pages twice in such a short period of time.

Comment: @LexLi I am skeptical that VS 2015 is an issue,VS 2015 should just be using the installed .NET Core tooling, in my case: .NET Core 1.0.1 tools Preview 2

Comment: @LexLi Builds fine in VS 2017 RC

Comment: Then clearly it is an issue of preview 2. As the whole tool chain is moving to VS2017, you will soon be needing it daily.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi if you want to provide your comment as an answer I will award you the points

Comment: Sorry @LexLi, I was incorrect, I just discovered it is the postcompile cmd in my scripts, some problem  publishing the nuget package

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message was entirely misleading, it was my `postcompile` cmd to publish the library as a nuget package to my own nuget server that was failing:

```
  "scripts":
  {
    "postcompile":
    [
      "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %compile:Configuration%",
      "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NuGet\\nuget\" push \"%project:Directory%\\bin\\%compile:Configuration%\\%project:Name%.%project:Version%.nupkg\" -s http://foo/NugetServer/ -apikey testkey"
    ]
  }
```

That cmd is trying to call `C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\nuget.exe`

As I said, I cloned this project and did not create it, the developer who created the project has `C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\nuget.exe` installed.

I only had `C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet`, no nuget.exe, the folder existed because I have the Visual Studio 2015 nuget extension installed and the `.vsix` file lives there but no nuget.exe.

I simply downloaded nuget.exe [here](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html), **latest (v3.5.0)** and placed where my postcompile cmd expected it to be: C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet

Comment: Glad to see you find the cause, but moving to latest SDK is recommended as the preview builds are expiring.

Comment: Great hint, was the reason in my case too. Hoping for better SDK with the comeback of csproj in VS2017

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Download the 1.1 SDK, https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd
3. Reopen project in Visual Studio
4. Delete the project.lock.json (wait for restore)
5. Rebuild

Comment: I already have .net core 1.1 installed, I have deleted the .json.lock and waited for restore and the subsequent build still failed

Comment: try adding the runtime section (below the frameworks section):

Comment: "runtimes" : {
            "win10-x64": {}
 },

Comment: occurs on Windows 7 as well

Comment: tried adding the runtimes entry, no luck, I have added the build output to my question

Answer (score 0):

I have produced the scenerio. 
You could restore the package altogether. 
Follow the steps:
Right click on Project-> Click on Resotre Packages
And check your output.

Hope this would resolve your issue.

Comment: Also, i recommend you to use Visual Studio 2017 community or professional for high version of **.Net Core 2x .**